# Full Calendar v5.11.0 - How can we vertically stack overlapping events in timeGridWeek view using JavaScript

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar v5.11.0.

The scenario is that there can be multiple hour long sessions in a day and there can be 18-25 people in each session.
From Full Calendar perspective, people will be treated as 18-25 events with same start time and end time.

I want to show all of these people/event in one block on Full Calendar in vertically stacked manner. Full Calendar is showing vertically stacked events in dayGridMonth view but I want to show the same vertically stacked event blocks in timeGridWeek view.

Thank you for reading this far and I appreciate your valuable time to provide suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: It makes no sense to show that in time grid view, because time is the vertical axis. If all events start at the same time, then logically they must all start at the same vertical point,  otherwise visually it would appear that they start at different times

Comment: Perhaps you would be better using the timeline view, or using a single event to represent a session, with an additional popover box (or similar) implemented so that the user can easily see all participants by clicking or hovering on the event

Comment: I understand other perspective, however, for this project feature I need to show in vertical stack, the way I described on the question. Participant list needs to be visible on screen, popover or tooltip are not desirable.

Comment: You would still be better to make each session a single event then, and just list the participants in a description field, and modify the html of each event (via the appropriate callback) to show the list with line breaks between each one. I think that would work. The other idea (lots of events stacked vertically) isn't possible in fullcalendar because as I said earlier, it isn't logical and could mislead users.